# Android arcGIS map projections

Tags: android, dictionary, arcgis, map-projections

I am using ArcGIS API's in an Android application.  I have used Google API's before.  There is a projection calculation which is possible in Google API like below:

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        Point p = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp, p);//gp is a geoPoint computed earlier.
```

Question: Is there anything similar in ArcGIS API?

I have seen  `GeometryEngine.project(point p, spatialReference sr1, spatialReference sr2)` method in ArcGIS documentation.  But not sure how to use this to get the similar computation as above.  What spatialReference should I use to get the pixel coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the toScreenPoint() and toMapPoint() methods of the MapView class in com.esri.android.map

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/api/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html#toScreenPoint(com.esri.core.geometry.Point)